# How to specify DTD path to be picked from project path in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
        ...
       </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

How is it possible that hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd is picked up from java project path?

In other words, I want to make hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd work offline.

Comment: Did you download the dtd file ?

Comment: yes,I have downloaded it & placed in src folder. I want the project to pick it from src folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `dtd` file to the classpath and refer it as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: Getting following error:
  
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: unknown protocol: classpath Nested exception: unknown protocol: classpath
 at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
 ... 16 more